# Silverstripe Blog Module, link a custom Page to have BlogCategory

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a CustomPage that extends Page and I want to have a select to assign BlogCategories to a CustomPage.php

I have the following in CustomPage.php

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'Categories' => 'BlogCategory'
);

$fields->addFieldToTab(
      'Root.Main', 
       TagField::create(
            'Categories',
            'Add Categories',
            BlogCategory::get(),
            $this->Categories()
        )
        ->setCanCreate(true)
        ->setShouldLazyLoad(true)

    );
```

I have also added the following adjustments to BlogCategory.php

```
private static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'BlogPosts'       => 'BlogPost',
    'CustomPages'   => 'CustomPage',
);

public function CustomPages()
{
    $blogPosts = parent::CustomPages();

    $this->extend("updateGetCustomPages", $blogPosts);

    return $blogPosts;
}
```

**The problem:**

When I add a category and try to save, I get the following error in the top right corner of the cms:

> Error at line 71 of D:\webserver\htdocs\clients\sarah\puritan\framework\model\queries\SQLAssignmentRow.php

**EDIT 1:**
Some additional information. This is what I get in my web console:

> http://my-website.com/admin/pages/edit/EditForm 500 (Error at line 71 of X:..\my-website\framework\model\queries\SQLAssignmentRow.php)

Comment: Normally it helps to see what is the error, not just the what was the line number where the error occured. What is your Silverstripe version? If its below 4 you might be using the wrong version of the blog extension.

Comment: Hi @Olli Tyynelä , first of all thank you for your comment. I am using silverstripe 3.3.1, as for the Tagfield I believe 1.3.0.  But after looking at SQLAssignmentRow.php, at that function, parseAssignment, I think it's something related to how the categories are being save. Somewhere an empty arrray is sent or something like that.

Comment: If i comment out line 71 in SQLAssignmentRow.php, the one that gives a user_error(), it works. This makes it work BUT it's not good to change core code, so this solution doesn't do it.

Comment: Have you remembered to do dev/build with a flush so the relations are right? The actual error message would also probably help debugging the issue.